# Read database configurations from yml file

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

I need to read database configurations like url, username etc. to use enabling logging on database from a yml file.

I tried to use Apache Properties Configuration but I need to read .yml file so it didn't work. Because for example I want to read "user" info but in the file there are so many "user" keys.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use Apache Properties Configuration but I need to read .yml file so it didn't work. Because for example I want to read "user" info but in the file there are so many "user" key.

Answer (score 0):

```
<properties> 
       <entry key="jdbc.username">user</entry>
        <entry key="jdbc.password">name</entry>
   </properties>
```

Then use `Properties` to read:

```
            Properties property = new Properties();
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("E:/config.xml");
            property.loadFromXML(input);

            String username = property.getProperty("jdbc.username");
```